# Strongly typed partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net application and I have created a folder named Models inside it. I have a class named instructor in it. I am creating a partial view and making it strongly typed with this statement

```
@model RazorView.Models.Instructor
```

But I am getting this error :

The type name 'Models' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Mvc.RazorView'

public class _Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage> {

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your Namespace, [RazorView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.razorview%28VS.98%29.aspx) is used by System.Web.Mvc.